# Paginate from record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I use the gem `will-paginate`.

Lets suppose i have a model `records` that is sort by `created_at` and the client has the records until a specific record with the id 77. Now would it be possible to define for example:

```
 Records.paginate(:page => params[:record_id], :per_page => 30)
```

So that the pagination doesnt`t start at a specific page but at a record

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065174/items-page-and-will-paginate

Answer (score 0):

The unique alternative I can imagine is to add a `where` condition and sorting the results by id

```
 Records.where("id >= ?", params[:record_id]).order(id: :asc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)
```

This way you ensure that the record_id received is the first element in the pagination and all the results are after that one