# page number is not maintained on pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

I am listing my reports on reports index page. 10 reports are shown per page. If I am on 5th page and when click on any of the report, show page is displayed but then when I click back button then It goes to first page not on 5th page.

I am using `will_paginate-bootstrap` gem
Any suggestions on this

Comment: which pagination are you using?

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay I updated question

Answer (score 0):

```
page = (number_of_records_before_RECORD / number_of_records_per_page) + 1
```

this will solve your query, please visit below link

[Item's page and will_paginate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065174/items-page-and-will-paginate)

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I have gone through this link, I don't want to keep that page number in my url